Are there any overlap Between CPTAC-3 and TCGA-HNSC cohorts?
Below is an R code that I used to check for any overlaps between CPTAC-3 and TCGA-HNSC.
From GDC, I downloaded the biospecimen TSV file for Project ID CPTAC-3. Similarly, I downloaded the biospecimen TSV file for Project ID TCGA-HNSC.
I then compared both the sample IDs and case IDs to see if there were any matches between the IDs present in TCGA-HNSC and the entire CPTAC-3 cohort. As far as I know, the CPTAC-3 study began around 2016, which was around the time the TCGA study ended. However, I am still confused about whether they used the same samples from TCGA for proteomic characterization in CPTAC-3. Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated.
According to the R code there are no overlaps , not sure if this is correct
Thanks!
cptac <- read_delim("~/yyy/biospecimen.project-cptac-3.2024-10-18/sample.tsv")
Rows: 5748 Columns: 39                                                                                                 
── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Delimiter: "\t"
chr (39): project_id, case_id, case_submitter_id, sample_id, sample_submitter_id...

ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

tcga <- read_delim("~/yyy/biospecimen.project-tcga-hnsc.2024-10-18/sample.tsv")
Rows: 1578 Columns: 39                                                                                                 
── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Delimiter: "\t"
chr (38): project_id, case_id, case_submitter_id, sample_id, sample_submitter_id...
lgl  (1): is_ffpe

ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

cptac %>%
  select(sample_id, case_id) %>%
  head()
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  sample_id                            case_id                                                            
1 6986fe11-bd6f-40a4-abff-28edeb546d6d bf3941c0-1430-4b99-8d2e-b0e685cbf0b1
2 874cc72e-3024-46b6-92cd-2a5d376be989 bf3941c0-1430-4b99-8d2e-b0e685cbf0b1
3 c9354dc3-a0ef-4016-92d9-ff42f7c5f5db bf3941c0-1430-4b99-8d2e-b0e685cbf0b1
4 35fdc072-c2e1-4256-85cb-3c2a6902fec9 9f28fa0c-b5b1-4cd9-8320-e99e1e5e59c6
5 ffb4517e-4e9c-41d6-8cee-38f53811fd4a 9f28fa0c-b5b1-4cd9-8320-e99e1e5e59c6
6 85cb48e0-687b-4248-8c7c-42c38513bad1 322a57c2-82ef-45cd-986d-759bb3916919

tcga %>%
  select(sample_id, case_id) %>%
  head()
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  sample_id                            case_id                                                            
1 cbbe1ad3-5889-4c89-bdc4-92aa9dedaabc c4ad0479-8bef-4876-b423-fe83f222a60a
2 ed77d487-2a2d-4f30-b342-68b38ed68eee c4ad0479-8bef-4876-b423-fe83f222a60a
3 f4bc5fa7-70be-4f14-a104-0300ce252140 c4ad0479-8bef-4876-b423-fe83f222a60a
4 11f7fc0b-db09-4fa0-b7e3-a0e4ff51af02 f76ab158-2cf9-4df7-b6fe-727dd69a369f
5 6dc6b8a7-5e68-4ef8-9e8a-849eb9f2fede f76ab158-2cf9-4df7-b6fe-727dd69a369f
6 52cca481-6d27-49f6-b15d-eb539966f99b 80593c77-4530-413b-bb05-adca5d43bb82

compare_cohort <- function(id_col) {
  tcga_sample_ids <- tcga %>%
    select({{ id_col }}) %>%
    pull()

  cptac_sample_ids <- cptac %>%
      select({{ id_col }}) %>%
      pull()

  return(any(tcga_sample_ids %in% cptac_sample_ids))
}

compare_cohort(sample_id)
[1] FALSE

compare_cohort(case_id)
[1] FALSE


Have you resolved this issue? I'm also curious whether there are any overlapping samples between CPTAC3 and TCGA.
